# How to determine which objects are stored in an arraylist?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, collections

If I have 3 class called CPU,GPU,RAM and I stored these classes into an arraylist `ArrayList<Object> stock = new ArrayList<>()` what method can you use to return which class is stored in a certain index. Eg

```
stock = new ArrayList<>;
stock.add(new CPU());
stock.add(new GPU());
//method to determine which class is in index 0 
System.out.println(method);
Output: class packageName.CPU
```

Comment: Given your `inheritance` tag, I imagine your ultimate solution is to create an interface or abstract class named `Chip` from which the `CPU`, `GPU`, and `Memory` classes implement/extend. Then: `List< Chip > chips = new ArrayList<>();` and `chips.add( new CPU() ) ;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Only the first element

You can simply get the element 0, then the class and finally the name of it.

```
ArrayList<Object> stock = new ArrayList<>();

class CPU{};
class GPU{};

stock.add(new CPU());
stock.add(new GPU());

System.out.println(stock.get(0).getClass().getName());
```

and the output is what you want:

> com.example.example.model.CPU

### All the elements

If you need all the classes just add a foreach in the process:

```
stock.forEach(i -> {
    System.out.println(i.getClass().getName());
});
```

> com.example.example.model.CPU

> com.example.example.model.GPU

Answer (score 1):

use the `stock.get(index).getClass()` as pointed out by markspace this is horrible practice, better to have a base interface.

Comment: This is however bad practice.  Your list should take a Stock object (`ArrayList<Stock>`) and classes like CPU should extend Stock (`public class GPU extends Stock { ...`).  Stock should define common methods like `getName()` and `getPrice()` that you use instead of determining the exact type.

Comment: Yes this is bad practice will edit post to make it clear (thought that was obvious lol)

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I was actually commenting on the OP's remark, but they deleted it before I could finish typing.